# Peripheral BLE - Can Simulate BLE device on IOS using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, simulator, peripherals, bluetooth-peripheral

Is there any Flutter library to simulate BLE device on iOS?

Referred below link. But not working...
https://github.com/juliansteenbakker/flutter_ble_peripheral
https://github.com/dotintent/FlutterBleLib

Answer (score 0):

- Flustered is a client library only, and cannot emulate a Bluetooth device in peripheral mode. It has a companion package https://github.com/Polidea/blemulator_flutter but that is only for testing purposes (faking a simulated device).
- https://github.com/juliansteenbakker/flutter_ble_peripheral however is truly a plugin developed for implementing and advertising a BLE device with services and characteristics. Keep in mind that iOS is more restrictive about what you can do.
- We need more details than just "But not working...". What code have you written so far and what precise and exact errors you faced?
- If your goal is BLE beacon (iBeacon) specific then I see three plugins in the Flutter gems curated list of BLE plugins: https://fluttergems.dev/bluetooth-nfc-beacon/